# Passing a list as parameter in a call within a windows bat file

Tags: windows, scripting

For a set of project, I need to automate granting access to users and would write a *.bat

I would write something like this (but more complex):

```
@echo off
CALL :grant "user1 user2" "read write delete"
CALL :grant "groupa groupb" "read"

ECHO All Done
GOTO :eof

:grant
ECHO %0 is called with arguments %1 and %2
for %%a in (%1) do (
    for %%b in (%2) do (
        echo grant %%a %%b
        rem here come the actual commands
    )
)
EXIT /B
```

and expected output like this

```
:grant is called with arguments user1 user2 and read write delete
grant user1 read
grant user1 write 
grant user1 delete
grant user2 read
grant user2 write 
grant user2 delete
:grant is called with arguments groupa groupb and read
grant groupa read
grant groupb read
All Done
```

but in stead I get

```
:grant is called with arguments "user1 user2" and "read write delete"
grant "user1 user2" "read write delete"
:grant is called with arguments "groupa groupb" "read"
grant "groupa groupb" "read"
All Done
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
CALL :grant "user1 user2" "read write delete"
echo _
CALL :grant "groupa groupb" "read"

ECHO All Done
GOTO :eof

:grant
ECHO %0 is called with arguments %1 %2
set identities=%1
set accessList=%2
for %%a in (%identities:"=%) do (
    for %%b in (%accessList:"=%) do (
        echo grant %%a %%b
    )
)
EXIT /B
```